# inserting new node between two nodes, which are already in the linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, insert, linked-list

I am trying to insert a new Node to a linked List such that the new node is always inserted between two nodes, which are already in the list.This is my method:

```
public void insertAfter(ListNode after,Object x){
    if (head.next==null)
        insertFront(x);
    else {
        ListNode tmp=new ListNode(x,after.next);
        after=tmp;}
        size++;
    }
```

But when I call this method as ***list.insertAfter(list.head.next,"0");*** nothing happens.What is wrong here.I can't see anything wrong in this.Can someone please point out why this doesn't work.
Here's the full code :

```
public class Linked{
    private ListNode head;
    private int size;
    public Linked(){
        head=null;
        size=0;
    }
    // public void insertFront(Object item){
        // head=new ListNode(item,head);    
        // size++;
// }


public void removeFromHead(){
    if(head==null)
        return;
    if(head.next==null)
        head=null;
    else{
    head=head.next;
    }
}
public void removeFromEnd(){
if (head==null)
    return;
if(head.next==null)
    removeFromHead();
else{
    ListNode current=head;
    while(current.next.next!=null)
        current=current.next;
    current.next=null;

}
}
public void removeNext(ListNode current){
if(current==null)
    removeFromHead();
else if(current.next.next==null)
    removeFromEnd();
else current.next=current.next.next;
}
public String toString() {
    String result = " ";
    ListNode a=head;
    result+=a.item;
    while (a.next!=null){
        result +=" "+a.next.item;
        a=a.next;
    }

    return result;
}
public void insertFront(Object x){
    if(head==null)
            head=new ListNode(x);
    else 
        head=new ListNode(x,head);
    size++;
}
public void insertEnd(Object item){
if (head==null){ head=new ListNode(item);
}else{
    ListNode current=head;
    while(current.next!=null){
        current=current.next;
    }
    current.next=new ListNode(item);

    size++;}
}

public void insertAfter(ListNode after,Object x){
if (head.next==null)
    insertFront(x);
else {
    ListNode tmp=new ListNode(x,after);
    after=tmp;}
    size++;
}


public static void main (String args[]){
 Linked list=new Linked();
list.insertFront("a");
list.insertFront("c");
list.insertFront("d");
list.insertEnd("b");


list.insertAfter(list.head,"0");
System.out.println(list.toString());

}
```

}

Comment: why `size++` and `}` before it. are you calling this method in a loop. Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to help you.
Firstly A Node can be represented in 3 ways.
1)The whole Node (a memory address)
2)The data in Node represented by Node.data
3)The link in Node represented by Node.link

So always try what you want on paper before you program it.So here we go
Node A  Node New Node B
  __      __     __
 |**|    |**|   |**|
 |**|    |**|   |**|

Intially
Now A.link = B

End Result
We want A.link=New
New.Link =B

First and foremost thing 
First let us store A.link value in B.link(By doing so both point to Node B and we don't loose memory address of B we can also use temp Node but as you see here it is not required.)

Then let us  Store A.link = New(Now A points to New and New points to B)

I hope It was clear.
Coming to your question if you want to insert between first and second node you have to pass the first Node but you are passing second one.See if list.head solves the issue

Comment: I think what you have described here is what I am doing in `ListNode tmp=new ListNode(x,after);
    after=tmp;}`.I made the change as `list.insertAfter(list.head,"0");`.But still nothing get inserted